# Faulty address line

Tags: microcontroller, memory, firmware, ssd

how to find address line fault in microcontroller if microcontroller connected to external memory through address line? if given one line in address is faulty  how to pinpoint the particular line which is faulty ? and which code and logic we can use to pinpoint the fault lines

Comment: I want the answer logically if any bit manipulation possible through c code actually this question got asked in an SSD firmware interview

Comment: That is a hypothetical question and answer would depend on type of memory as well. So yes, any bit manipulations are possible, but the point is the task was given to you to see what solutions you come up with, not ask the internet for all possible solutions.

Comment: The interview is already done now  there is not that much about this so I just wanted to know what is the right solution @justme if you can help I will be thankful

Comment: There is no one right solution to this problem. There are multiple ways it can be approached, and depending on how and why the address line appears to be stuck only some approaches may work. For example, if the line is floating, a different solution reveals it than jusy having it stuck high or stuck low.

Comment: in the  question it is  already given one address line is faulty and can we check and pinpoint the faulty address line using c code ?@Justme

Comment: It depends in which way it is faulty. Stuck high, stuck low, floating, getting AC coupling from nearby address or data lines. Sure you can start by checking each scenario and rule out what is not the problem, leading up to the most difficult scenarios that when a nearby address line and data line change at the same time they flip the weak faulty address line. Possible. But maybe instead of just C code, you need to use an oscilloscope to see which line is faulty and in which way, a logic analyzer may not show anything out of ordinary.

Comment: Questions like this asked in an interview do not target a solution, but the way you approach the issue. During the answer you might even conclude that the question as asked cannot be answered. That would be what the interviewer expected.

Answer (score 1):

Program the microcontroller to give a specific address line and look at it with the logic analyzer you might want to try address 0 and all ones to start. If you see a line not turning on when you send it all ones on the address line then there is a problem. The other problem might be clocking especially if the memory interface is high speed or more than 50 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for diagnostic software, rather than hardware, techniques, you can look up the classical memory tests.

When RAM and general electronic construction was considerably less reliable than currently, it was usual to have basic memory tests built into power-on testing.  Sometimes thsi was just to see how much memory there was, sometimes it really was for testing.  Sometimes the programs were extremely slow (days) and had very sophisticated algorithms.  [Wikipedia article on memory testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_tester#Software_testers) is a good place to start.  Remember we're often testing for problematic data lines as well as address lines, and that makes it a lot more difficult.  Have a look at [Memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/tech_memtest-algoritm.html) algorithms for good ideas.

In essence you have a function *fn(a)* which calculates a data value for a given address.  The function should have the property *fn(a) != fn(fault(a))*, for a fault function which is the error you're trying to find.

You write every location under test with *fn(a)*, then read them all back and compare *memory(a)* with *fn(a)*.  If they are different, something is wrong.

Easy varieties of *fn* are:

- Identity function: if your memory is wider than your address, just put *a* in each location.
- Partial identity: if your memory is, in the limit, one bit wide, and your addresses are *n* bits: do *n* runs, copying one bit of the address to the memory.
- A pseudorandom sequence
- A timestamp

Try things like this Python3 experiment to make good algorithms:

```
n = 3
memory = [0] * (1 << n)
def fn(x):
    return x
def fault(a):
    return a | 2
def bits(x):
    return [i for i in range(0, n) if x&(1<<i)]
for a in range(0, 1 << n):
    memory[fault(a)] = fn(a)
for a in range(0, 1 << n):
    r = memory[fault(a)]
    print("a=%x fn(a)=%x r=%x" % (a, fn(a), r))
    if r != fn(a):
        print("  error, perhaps address line", bits(r^a))
```

WHich when run shows:

```
a=0 fn(a)=0 r=2
  error, perhaps address line [1]
a=1 fn(a)=1 r=3
  error, perhaps address line [1]
a=2 fn(a)=2 r=2
a=3 fn(a)=3 r=3
a=4 fn(a)=4 r=6
  error, perhaps address line [1]
a=5 fn(a)=5 r=7
  error, perhaps address line [1]
a=6 fn(a)=6 r=6
a=7 fn(a)=7 r=7
```